# How is the long method way of doing below code in "Lambda Expressions" in the past?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
                yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I see its an Extension method where it returns an item by passing in a combination of kinda like two classes in it. So, with Visual Studio, a one liner code give out the results. I think its because of the "this" making it an extension method. I'm just curious. How will this two classes passed in here look like in long method?